# Windows Phone 8: Share an Image from Assets folder

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to use ShareMediaTask to share an images inside my application's Assets folder, here's the code I use:

```
private async void MenuShare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder installationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    StorageFile file = await installationFolder.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\shanghaimetro-1.png");

    var shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask
    {
        FilePath = file.Path
    };
    shareMediaTask.Show();
}
```

But the standard Windows Phone sharing screen never appers. It just go back to the page where I came after click the share button.

In debug mode, I am able to see the file.Path is:

```
C:\Data\Programs\{E6357D2C-2888-448E-8990-4C8D37510514}\Install\Assets\shanghaimetro-1.png
```

It should be correct path.

Is there anything wrong in this code? How can I make it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the photo to the `MediaLibrary` and then use the `GetPath()` extension method (`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions` namespace) to retrieve the path. Assign this path to the `FilePath` property